# Copy dedicated values from a text file and store inside Excel sheet using MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I have several text files which have data stored in them in following manner:

```
PDU            Parameter          Value            
06 00          Monitor ID         ExhaustGasSensorMonitorBank1Sensor1
               testvalue          0.009
               Test ID            0X87
06 01          Monitor ID         ExhaustGasSensorMonitorBank1Sensor1
               testvalue          0.009
               Test ID            0X87
```

and so on...

---

---

---

---

I Need to copy and store the values given in the Parameter and value columns against PDU values in an Excel sheet. I am fairly new to MATLAB programming and I know xlsread can be used in this Situation but I dont know how. Any Kind of help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried reading `xlsread` https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html ?

Comment: yes i have read it. i think xls read is used to read data from an Excel sheet and return data in the form of a Matrix. What i want is that i have some text files and i want to Import that data in an Excel sheet.

Comment: Why do you need MATLAB for this? Excel is very good at importing text files.

Comment: it is just a self assessment exercise. i can do this in C or PHP but somehow am unable to find a solution for this in MATLAB